# SQL Server views are empty even though data exists in underlying tables

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm running Azure SQL Server and there's a problem I have that relates to views. I have a view (which I will refer to as `viewC`) that is built on a `UNION ALL` of two other views, i.e.

```
SELECT ColA
      ,ColB
FROM dbo.viewA

UNION ALL

SELECT ColA
      ,ColB
FROM dbo.viewB
```

If I truncate all the tables in the underlying `viewA` and `viewB` views, and re-import the data in these truncated tables, sometimes `viewC` is still empty if `SELECT` from it. This behavior is very odd and I was wondering if it could be related to caching or something like this.

I first noticed this might be related to the `UNION ALL` operation somehow. I remember having issues when I used `*` instead of specifying the individual columns, even though `viewA` and `viewB` had the exact same schema.
I.e. `viewC` was empty when I ran this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.viewA

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM dbo.viewB
```

The view seems to work again if I manually `SELECT` individual tables, then `viewA` and `viewB` and finally `ViewC` respectively. Very odd!

Are there any table hints or view hints I can try? Does anyone know what this 'bug' might be related to?

Comment: I suppose you should look into the underlying queries of your views. You haven't posted your corresponding CREATE VIEW statements, so I am not able to say anything about this.

Comment: You get results from `SELECT * FROM dbo.viewA` and `SELECT * FROM dbo.viewB` separately? But not from `SELECT * FROM dbo.viewA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM dbo.viewB`? That I cannot understand either.

Comment: How many rows in each table? Are you using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio? I've created a same test, it works well in MSSM.

Answer (score 2):

This issues may be due to a change in the table structure.

You can use `sp_refreshview` system stored procedure to refresh the view.

```sql
exec sp_refreshview 'schema.view_name'
```